# What happened in April 2020 on devops.se?

Tags: discussion

According to site traffic stats, April 2020 seems to mark the start of a decline of this site:

[image: 7 week average visit on site]

The traffic was roughly steadily climbing (out of each year Christmas and new year), the first dent around October 2019 is well known and it was when I stepped down as moderator.

But Early 2020 seemed to catch-up and restart the previous trend, up to April 2020 where things fall down terribly.
I thought about the pandemic as a reason but it seems in contradiction with [SO Blog post showing a surge in traffic networkwide](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/pandemic-changed-traffic-trends-stack-exchange-sites/).

Early 2021 show the usual uptick as every year, so I left it just for the sake of completeness.

What happened on this site ? And is it only this site or a more general trend ?

Comment: I think it would be useful to compare traffic stats with mods of other communities. An overall number for SE isn't too helpful here.

Comment: It's been a time when CM were monitoring every site's Meta post with "meta tags" (red ones like featured, support*, etc.), I was kinda hopping someone has insight about this site and that a CM can shed some lights about the overall status of sites.

Comment: I agree with @Adam. I think the most useful insight would be to compare other (preferably beta) communities to see what their traffic is like. Is it possible to see specific question tag traffic? It would be interesting to see what our most popular tags are, and if there is any correlation to a loss in traffic for a specific tag to the overall site traffic.

Comment: Well, I think a query in SEDE can give that. For the stats, sadly I can only compare with SO, I don't have 10k elsewhere, maybe a mod could ask in TL?

Comment: Interesting! I wish I could put a bounty on this.